# Who was the captain of the ship that was pruned in Loki episode 5

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, loki

We see a ship appearing to be from around the 1800s or so landing the void near Alison, the camera focuses on the captain as if he was some kind of important historic figure

Who was it?

Comment: Oh and who is Alison?

Comment: 1800s? I implore you to spend a few minutes looking at naval pictures of the 1800s vs 1940s.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> We see a ship appearing to be from around the 1800s or so landing the void near Alison, the camera focuses on the captain as if he was some kind of important historic figure

I assume you are referring to this ship and this sailor...

[image]

[image]

In fact the ship was commissioned in 1943 and was the [*USS Eldridge*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Eldridge). The sailor is no-one special but is rather indicating where to fire the guns.

The *USS Eldridge* is, supposedly, famous as the subject of the legendary [Philadelphia Experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philadelphia_Experiment) now widely debunked as a hoax.

Comment: A hoax in _this_ timeline...

Comment: exactly what was being lookedfor, I knew it was something